# How to get the current nuxt layout from within a component/template?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt provides a way to dynamically set a `layout` within a component, but is there a way to determine which layout is in use from within the `<template>` e.g. `v-if="layout === 'me'"`? For example, I want to use a single route `/c/dream` and provide one layout for a user who is authenticated and another layout for a user who is not authenticated. If I can determine the layout in use from within the template, then I can structure the HTML according to the layout. I've inspected the `this` object in a component and do not see a way to determine which layout is in use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to rely on Vue provide/inject feature to pass down this information to all child components.

Your layouts would provide the name of the layout:

```js
// layouts/authenticated.vue
export default {
  provide() {
    return { layout: "authenticated" };
  },
};
```

Your page components or any child component can inject `layout` to determine which layout is currently in use.

`pages/c/dream.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="layout == 'authenticated'">
      <!-- custom UI for authenticated users -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // Determines which layout is currently in use
  inject: ["layout"],

  // Decide which layout to use
  // based on Nuxt context as an example
  layout(context) {
    return context.user ? "authenticated" : "default";
  },
};
</script>
```

*I have to admit, it's strange to implement `layout(context)` in order to set the layout we want to use and have to inject `layout` to access the value in the same component.*